# GPUImage: cancelling GPUImageMovieWriter

Tags: ios, gpuimage

Is there any way to cancel/stop `GPUImageMovieWriter` and `GPUImageMovie` after running `startRecording` and `startProcessing`?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, a new method was added to the `GPUImageMovie` that allows to cancel the processing of a video file:

```
- (void)cancelProcessing;
```

This will allow you to effectively cancel the processing of the video and no more frames will be processed.

Take into account that your `GPUImageMovieWriter`'s completionBlock will be called anyway, so you should have some kind of flag to check if the block was called for a successful finish or by a cancellation.

Here is some example code:

```
- (void)processVideo
{
    _wasCancelled = NO;

    self.imageMovie = [self createImageMovie];
    self.filter = [self createFilter];
    [imageMovie addTarget:filter]
    self.movieWriter = [self createMovieWriter];

    [self.movieWriter startRecording];
    [self.imageMovie startProcessing];

    [self.movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        [self.filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
        [self.movieWriter finishRecording];

        if (!_wasCancelled) {
            // Do stuff with the video
        }
    }];
}

- (void)cancelVideoProcessing
{
    _wasCancelled = YES;
    [self.imageMovie cancelProcessing];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that self.movieWriter is GPUImageMovieWriter,
you need to set a callback before invoking startRecording and startProcessing:

```
[self.movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self finishFilter];
}];
```

And then you can stop the image processing with:

```
[self.movieWriter endProcessing];
```

And the callback is:

```
- (void)finishFilter {
    //remove all targets from your filter chain calling "removeAllTargets"
    //then:
    [self.movieWriter finishRecording];
    self.movieWriter.completionBlock = nil;
    self.movieWriter = nil;
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to "finish" it? When I say "cancel" I really mean cancel; I don't want to save a partial movie.

Answer (score 0):

Why. There is a cancel recording option.

```
[self.movieWriter cancelRecording];
```

The videos are not saved if it is interrupted in any way.